# Dell Inspiron 15-5558 - A battery with low health is detected, charged, but not used

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, dell-inspiron

I've been using Dell Inspiron 15-5558 laptop for more than 8 years without replacing the battery (cause I've been mostly using AC charger only) and today I've encountered an issue when the laptop has stopped using it completely. The charging indicator is flashing orange. The battery shows up in the BIOS as almost fully charged (99%) with the message "Battery needs to be replaced". When I unplug the AC adapter the laptop immediately shuts down. I also ran a system diagnostics from the boot mode (F12), and it told me that "The battery is reaching the end of its usable life". Battery health is at 26% now, so it's technically not dead yet.

Is there a way to told the system to keep using this battery until its health drops to, like, 15%? If that's not possible at all I'll have to buy a new battery, but I want to know if there're any workarounds.

Comment: Battery health figures are just guesswork. if it immediately switches off when unplugged, consider it 'dead'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8 years is end of life (even longer than end of life in most cases) for any rechargeable battery (computer, electronics, even automobiles). This applies to battery age and includes light use as well. Batteries (after all) are just a can of chemicals plus electrodes).

So yes, you need to replace the battery.

Your computer should support battery threshold management (my 11 year old Lenovo does). There should be a Dell app to set it and you may need to update BIOS.

Then with a new battery, set battery charge management to 80 % (start at 75% and stop at 80%). This is the generally accepted charge level for rechargeable batteries.

Your computer needs a battery to function and so far as I know, no workarounds  (common question)

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider buying a new battery.